# Visual Studio 2015 Community: Setup Failed! Installation Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, build-tools

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Community (with updates) on Windows 7 x64, but in the start of the installation, when it is about to install Build Tools 14.0 (x86) it fails. I do not know why this happens and i have tried to find answers but nothing i do seems to work. Please report if you possibly know and answer and a solution.

Here is a screenshot:

[Click here][1]

It's in swedish but it says:

Microsoft Build Tools 14.0 (x86): A fatal error occured during installation

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015: %1 is not a valid Win32-program

Visual Studio Update Prerequisite: %1 is not a valid Win32-program

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi Targeting Pack: User stopped the installation

Please help...

Here is the a part of the log file i think the error is in:

```
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:33]i338: Acquiring package: netfx_451mtpack, payload: cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E, download from: prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25123.00.00&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=00C0175A9278942188A615441E055714F55FC693
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:32:48]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed authenticode verification of payload: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:32:48]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to verify signature of payload: cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:32:48]e310: Failed to verify payload: cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E, error: 0x800b0003, delete: Yes
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:32:48]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to cache payload: cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:48]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2146762749 (0x800B0003), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=False, Package Action=Verify, Package Id=netfx_451mtpack
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:48]e314: Failed to cache payload: cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E from working path: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\{04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01}\cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E, error: 0x800b0003.
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:48]e349: Application requested retry of payload: cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E, encountered error: 0x800b0003. Retrying...
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:48]w343: Prompt for source of package: netfx_451mtpack, payload: cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E, path: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\{1C9EE3C5-F6AF-44DC-8E1F-66BED962D134}\packages\netfx_451mtpack\netfx_451mtpack.cab
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:48]i000: MUX:  Next Source: Web, Attempted: 2, Limit:3
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:48]i000: MUX:  Source retrieved: Web
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:48]i000: MUX:  Sleep for 3 seconds before retrying
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:51]i000: MUX:  Package:netfx_451mtpack, PayloadId:cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E Url: prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25123.00.00&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=00C0175A9278942188A615441E055714F55FC693, Attempting count: 2
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:51]i000: MUX:  Skipping as it is the same as last unconfirmed source: Web
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:32:51]i338: Acquiring package: netfx_451mtpack, payload: cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E, download from: bits://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25123.00.00&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=00C0175A9278942188A615441E055714F55FC693
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: VCRedistD11x64 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 362042805  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '0'
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i319: Applied execute package: VCRedistD11x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[1D0C:1BB0][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {8CE767E5-878E-47F9-87C2-813D72D06BAE}, version: 1.0.25123.00, package: vs_vshubcore
[1D0C:1BB0][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i325: Registering dependency: {04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01} on package provider: {8CE767E5-878E-47F9-87C2-813D72D06BAE}, package: vs_vshubcore
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[1D0C:1BB0][2016-05-03T19:33:01]i301: Applying execute package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DF27D91D-516E-4DA1-92AC-7D7D59B2D99E}v14.0.25123\packages\BuildTools_MSBuild_x86\BuildTools_MSBuild.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 2908 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 1935 ErrorMessage: An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core,fileVersion="14.0.25123.0",version="14.0.0.00000",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A",processorArchitecture="MSIL"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. 
[1D0C:1BB0][2016-05-03T19:33:03]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[1D0C:1BB0][2016-05-03T19:33:03]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 897024  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 512000
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908.  Result Detail:InstallFiles Restart:None
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. , Result Detail=InstallFiles, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i319: Applied execute package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[1D0C:1BB0][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i318: Skipped rollback of package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908.  Result Detail:InstallFiles Restart:None
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i319: Applied rollback package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
[1D0C:1BB0][2016-05-03T19:33:03]i351: Removing cached package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DF27D91D-516E-4DA1-92AC-7D7D59B2D99E}v14.0.25123\
[0554:0B10][2016-05-03T19:33:11]e000: Error 0x80070642: UX aborted on download progress.
[0554:0B10][2016-05-03T19:33:11]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to send progress from BITS job.
[0554:0B10][2016-05-03T19:33:11]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failure while sending progress during BITS job modification.
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:33:11]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed attempt to download URL: 'bits://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25123.00.00&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=00C0175A9278942188A615441E055714F55FC693' to: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\{04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01}\cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E'
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:33:11]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to acquire payload from: 'bits://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25123.00.00&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=00C0175A9278942188A615441E055714F55FC693' to working path: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\{04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01}\cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E'
[0554:1DB4][2016-05-03T19:33:11]e313: Failed to acquire payload: cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E to working path: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\{04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01}\cab135D64C43B6E80A29EB363DD9339DB8E, error: 0x80070642.
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: tfs_storyboardingcoreres_x64_enu, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{965B81C8-C45E-39B6-997A-CD43D6EA787D}v14.95.25118\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: tfs_storyboardingcore_x64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{1850F701-7CCE-3AE9-9FC2-D4D75837A39E}v14.95.25118\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: tfs_officeintegrationcoreres_x64_enu, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{D59EAE46-00A3-38EB-BC47-E02D09725E4A}v14.95.25118\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: tfs_officeintegrationcore_x64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{041FD3D8-612C-3CB2-AB44-1E7B79990C37}v14.95.25118\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: vsbsln_res_28, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{83B181F2-20B8-4F00-8E71-C66E951A8D4F}v14.0.23107\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: vsbsln_neu_28, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DF32E41C-24AD-4A87-B43A-B38553B1806E}v14.0.23107\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_Res_amd64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{388D7468-1CCA-40C8-9F08-4C20E972E922}v14.0.25123\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_Res_x86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{CBE7F62C-646C-46C3-9AB4-A3F71E5A68CC}v14.0.25123\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_amd64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7F017105-282F-4091-B16A-F8B8A69B0325}v14.0.25123\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DF27D91D-516E-4DA1-92AC-7D7D59B2D99E}v14.0.25123\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]w353: Unable to remove cached package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DF27D91D-516E-4DA1-92AC-7D7D59B2D99E}v14.0.25123\, reason: 0x80070003. Continuing...
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: vs_preclean_vs, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\4FBF48D9-BED3-36CE-A441-6A5F2B8F8CFE\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: VSSetupUtility_Start_vs_community, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\A7F8FA04-FE26-3C9F-B54B-58EB0B5FF075\
[1D0C:15D0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i351: Removing cached package: Preparation_Uninstall_vs_community, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9DE9F4DD-A257-3EF1-90C8-646644AF9B94\
[1D0C:1BB0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[1D0C:1BB0][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 477458432  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 67425968128 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 67425968128 bytes
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  Watson Bucketting Parameters
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  P1 - vs_community
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  P2 - 14.0.25123.00.00
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  P3 - 14.0.25123
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  P4 - Install
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  P5 - Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  P8 - The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. 
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i000: MUX:  P9 - InstallFiles
[0554:1C94][2016-05-03T19:33:11]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag3IB.png
```

Comment: Check the installation error logs

Comment: i do not understand it @Gusman

Comment: At least find on the logs where the exception has been recorded and post it (post it on english ;) )

Comment: @Gusman, i did but i don't understand what the error is

Comment: how do i post it? @Gusman (excuse me if you think i am retarded)

Comment: Edit your question and add it, you should have an "edit" link on the bottom part of your question, below the tags list

Comment: Ok, the 2908 error usually happens because a previous .net framework installation corrupted, try to uninstall manually all the versions of .net on your machine and try again the installation, also there is a cleanup tool which would repair most of these errors: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

Comment: Also, there are some errors about authenticode not verified, try to re-download the vs installer, maybe it has been corrupted.

Comment: i have redownloaded it many times since i can't sometimes open it again because it says it requires a newer version of Windows @Gusman

Comment: Woah, it sounds like your O.S. is corrupted, maybe the registry, maybe you have some kind of virus... try to download it on another machine and use that installer.

Comment: Do you use any kind of proxy/vpn?

Comment: what is that? @Gusman

Comment: Ok, then no, you don't use them XD. A proxy is a program which routes connections, and an VPN is a private tunnel through Internet.

Comment: I think so @Gusman, is AVG a vpn?

Comment: No, AVG is an antivirus, BUT it filters network connections, it can perfectly break any internet download if it has any problem, try to deactivate completelly any antivirus you have before downloading and installing VS.

Comment: I have tried to deactivate AVG before installing but i did not work either @Gusman

Comment: Then try the previous solutions I gave you, else the ultimate repair-all solution is...format c:, format your PC and reinstall the O.S., for extreme cases it's the only thing that will work.

Comment: it did not work to uninstall all versions of .net, and i wonder why it always fails on Build Tools? @Gusman

Comment: Have you tried the repair tool I linked?

Comment: i have, but that was before i uninstalled .NET, maybe i should try again? @Gusman

Comment: It will not hurt to try it again.

Comment: Also, the first problem I see is not the Build tools installation but the netfx_451mtpack download, which gets corrupted, check your network status (failed cables, hung routers, etc), it seems like something is messing with your network.

Comment: Finally, if nothing of these works for you, a better place to ask is the VS forums, there you will get Microsoft support: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps I took:

1. I restarted the system.
2. I went to task manager and end task for **all Microsoft Visual studio setup running**. **In my case, I had 3 running at the same time. This can be seen around here:**
   [task manager. end all the task relating to Microsoft visual studio setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wCnW.png)
3. Goto programs and features, visual studio community --> change --> repair or if you have the **.ISO file**, you can run it again. choose repair for either option. **I used the .ISO file** 
   NOTE: I was internet connected when running the repair.
4. Boom!!! it starts repairing and then you are good to go.
5. After repair, it will request for a restart. Click on restart and then you have your visual studio up and running

Answer (score 0):

Some file is corrupted or at least Windows thinks it.
You should try to absolutely uninstall Visual Studio with all of its doomed components.
Then install again.

Problem is that in most of cases uninstall also can't be completed because that corrupted file bloks uninstallation ad installer drop an error.

No problemo. In this case you should to use the magnificent *Visual Studio Uninstaller*
This application remove whole Visual Studio completely, totally and entirely.

Download from here: https://github.com/microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

After that you are able to install Visual Studio whitout any problem.

(You need .net framework 4.x installed on your machine to use *Visual Studio Uninstaller*)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is pretty easy solution for fixing all xxx3 errors. Download **Visual C++ v56.exe**, it will remove corrupted files and make impossible installation possible again. Tested on Autodesk 3D Studio MAX, working every time.